# Can't generate a tikz matrix, using expl3

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, expl3, tikz-matrix

Suppose, I want to generate a matrix of nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
[
    row  sep=2mm,
] (matr)
{
  \node[draw] (1) {1};\\
  \node[draw] (2) {2};\\
  \node[draw] (3) {3};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to do it, using expl3 `for` loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
[
    row  sep=2mm,
] (matr)
{
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \l__text_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 3 }
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__text_tl {\node[draw] (#1) {#1};\\}
  }
  \l__text_tl
  \ExplSyntaxOff
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The compiler fails with message:

```
! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> 
}
l.21 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not change catcodes in the argument of another command, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \l__text_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 3 }
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__text_tl {\node[draw] (#1) {#1};\\}
  }

\let\foo\l__text_tl
  \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
[
    row  sep=2mm,
] (matr)
{
\foo
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a basic restriction of the way TeX tokenises file characters, `\verb`, `\makeatletter`, `\ExplSyntaxOn` all have the restriction that they must be used at the top level.

Answer (score 7):

The **main** point to note really is that the `expl3` language was never intended for document level usage just like the internals of LaTeX2e (having `@` in their names) are not supposed to show up there. Instead those languages have been developed to support package development.

Thus within a LaTeX2e package the conventions of LaTeX2e are automatically set up (which is basically `@` being a letter) and within a LaTeX3 package the conventions for LaTeX3 are automatically enabled.

However, sometimes it is necessary to add/update code **in the preamble of a document** and recognizing this, LaTeX2e offers `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and LaTeX3/expl3 offers `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`. But those are for preamble usage and in general it is better to put such code into a package, which could then be reused.

So you could think of providing a command that does the necessary work for you, e.g., `\boxednumbers` which does everything including the matrix command, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xparse}
 \ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__text_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\boxednumbers{ O{2mm} m }
   {
     \tl_clear:N\l__text_tl
     \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #2 }
                   {   \tl_put_right:Nn \l__text_tl {\node[draw] (##1) {##1};  \\ } }
     \matrix [row~  sep=#1] (matr)
           { 
             \l__text_tl
           };
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}   \boxednumbers{5};       \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}   \boxednumbers[5mm]{3};  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There is one important point to note here:

- `tikz` was designed under 2e conditions and it doesn't know about `expl3` conventions.

So executing `tikz` commands that do parsing in the middle of `expl3` code is likely to cause trouble, which is why we can't simply execute `\node` in that loop, but instead build a line of code to be executed later. For the same reason I had to say `row~ sep` instead of `row sep` as the normal space vanishes within `expl3` code.
So in summary the mix and match of 2e code with `expl3` is a little tricky in places.